# HTTP status codes as atoms in put_status

Tags: controller, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to write a controller action with Phoenix and Elixir. When everything goes according to plan, I set the http status code with this line in:

```
 put_status :ok
```

and that makes a world of sense to me. It maps nicely to a 200 http code. However, I'm working on the not-green-path and cannot for the life of me figure out what atoms to use for the other http codes. I found a reference to :not_found online somewhere, which I'm assuming maps to a 404.

I'm trying to return a [http-status-code-422](/questions/tagged/http-status-code-422). Currently, I can get the job done with:

```
put_status 422
```

but I'd rather use the appropriate atom if such a thing exists.

Comment: by way of completely guessing, I discovered that :unprocessable_entity is what I wanted, but I still don't know where to find a list of these. If such a thing doesn't exist I can just keep going along trying to guess the atoms.

Comment: Is it reasonable to assume that the atom becomes the Official HTTP status code text lower cased and spaces replaced with underscores?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The complete list is available in the [documentation for `Plug.Conn.Status`](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Conn.Status.html). 422 is, as you guessed, `:unprocessable_entity`.

> ### Known status codes
>
> The following status codes can be given as atoms with their
>   respective value shown next:
>
> - `:continue` - 100
> - `:switching_protocols` - 101
> - `:processing` - 102
> - `:ok` - 200
> - `:created` - 201
> - `:accepted` - 202
> - `:non_authoritative_information` - 203
> - `:no_content` - 204
> - `:reset_content` - 205
> - `:partial_content` - 206
> - `:multi_status` - 207
> - `:already_reported` - 208
> - `:instance_manipulation_used` - 226
> - `:multiple_choices` - 300
> - `:moved_permanently` - 301
> - `:found` - 302
> - `:see_other` - 303
> - `:not_modified` - 304
> - `:use_proxy` - 305
> - `:reserved` - 306
> - `:temporary_redirect` - 307
> - `:permanent_redirect` - 308
> - `:bad_request` - 400
> - `:unauthorized` - 401
> - `:payment_required` - 402
> - `:forbidden` - 403
> - `:not_found` - 404
> - `:method_not_allowed` - 405
> - `:not_acceptable` - 406
> - `:proxy_authentication_required` - 407
> - `:request_timeout` - 408
> - `:conflict` - 409
> - `:gone` - 410
> - `:length_required` - 411
> - `:precondition_failed` - 412
> - `:request_entity_too_large` - 413
> - `:request_uri_too_long` - 414
> - `:unsupported_media_type` - 415
> - `:requested_range_not_satisfiable` - 416
> - `:expectation_failed` - 417
> - `:im_a_teapot` - 418
> - `:misdirected_request` - 421
> - `:unprocessable_entity` - 422
> - `:locked` - 423
> - `:failed_dependency` - 424
> - `:upgrade_required` - 426
> - `:precondition_required` - 428
> - `:too_many_requests` - 429
> - `:request_header_fields_too_large` - 431
> - `:internal_server_error` - 500
> - `:not_implemented` - 501
> - `:bad_gateway` - 502
> - `:service_unavailable` - 503
> - `:gateway_timeout` - 504
> - `:http_version_not_supported` - 505
> - `:variant_also_negotiates` - 506
> - `:insufficient_storage` - 507
> - `:loop_detected` - 508
> - `:not_extended` - 510
> - `:network_authentication_required` - 511

Comment: For the record, I've bookmarked this page. I wish I could give you additional points for that :)